# Fitting a surface to collection of 3D data points in java

Tags: java, 3d, regression, geometry-surface, best-fit-curve

Hi I have a cloud of XYZ data points. I want to estimate a surface which best fits these points, so that later on I can input an XY pair and get back the Z value where this XY pair lies on the surface.

Is there an existing Java library that will estimate a surface for me?

If not, can anyone recommend me stuff to read which will describe the methods for calculating this?

If possible, I want to be able to weight the points (Some points are less reliable and so should have less effect on the finished surface).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this seems to only talk about 2D regression. 

"Regression models involve the following variables:
The unknown parameters, denoted as β, which may represent a scalar or a vector.
The independent variables, X.
The dependent variable, Y."

Comment: Yep, that's the basic case.  It then extends to multivariate regression.  It's not really my area, though, so I can't provide any specific advice!  (However, you may find better help at http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Ahaaaa, i was getting thrown off by the x independents and y dependents, thinking those could only refer to x and y values. If I've got this right, I think i can chuck the Z values in the y dependents and the x independents are a series of {1, x, y, xy, xx, yy} for quadratic or {1, x, y, xx, yy, xy, xxx, yyy, xxy, yyx} for cubic etc?

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem is best solved with [linear least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares). However I wouldn't try reading the wikipedia article, it seems to be written for mathematicians.

The idea is to change the problem into a linear optimization one. In your case i'd try to fit a 2D polynomial. This is an equation in the form:

```
z(x, y) = A + Bx + Cy + Dx^2 + Exy + Ey^2 + Fx^3 + Gx^2y + Hxy^2 + Iy^3 + ...
```

You get the idea. For a given dataset, the task is reduced to finding the parameters A through I that best fit the data points. This kind of problem is easily solved by linear least squares.

[Have a look at this code for fitting ellipses to 3D data points.](https://github.com/BokiSoft/EllipsoidFit/tree/master/EllipsoidFit/src/ellipsoidFit) With some effort you can adapt that to fit polynomials in the form I described above.

Good luck!

Comment: Indeed, the Wikipedia article is not the best introduction to the topic.  But acquiring some basic background in the subject is probably advisable, before simply applying "arbitrary" techniques ;)